# How to make Mail use standard signature separator?

Tags: mail.app, signature

I am using many signatures under `Mail`.
I noticed that unlike many professionnal E-mail programs `Mail`
doesn't automatically include the standard E-mail signature separator.

The command:

```
defaults read com.apple.mail | egrep '(--|sep|sig)'
```

didn't let me a lot of hope.

Is there any way to configure `Mail` so that it will automatically include the standard separator `-- \n` with any signature ?

Answer (score 4):

You need to manually add the [sig-dashes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signature_block#Signatures_in_Usenet_postings), `--\n`, to the top of your signatures within Mail.app:

- Mail (menu) > Preferences > Signatures

It may be possible to automate the changing of signatures, see [How to change/customize mail signature in Mountain Lion?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/52821) for details of Mail's signature file format.

Comment: This is what I'm doing :). But since I'm using different E-mail clients, and I regularly change my signature__s on them, I would appreciate to avoid repetitive and boring manual work for Mail.

Comment: You may be able to automate your signature updates or apply bulk changes. The answer has been updated for this possibility.